# Resolving postgis "type geometry does not exist" issue on installing tiger_geocode extension?

Tags: postgis, geometry, tiger, reverse-geocoding

I have installed `postgis extension` in my db.  I have few columns associated with its type in few tables and now I would like to use `reverse geocode` functionality in my app.  Hence I tried to create `postgis_tiger_geocoder` extension and I get the error as

```
type geometry does not exist
```

I tried to drop the extension and create it newly and it works. But I lose all my columns with the type

```
postgis.geography(Polygon,4326)
postgis.geography(Point,4326)
```

So, how can I repair or reinstall postgis extension without losing the columns and install the postgis_tiger_extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be able to find it if postgis is in your database search path.

Trying doing this:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db SET search_path=public,postgis;
```

Then connect to your database again and do:

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Comment: I tried this and when creating "fuzzystrmatch", it shows as ERROR:  extension "fuzzystrmatch" already exists and on creating "postgis_tiger_geocoder" extension, I get the same ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist.

Comment: leave out the fuzzystrmatch part then since you have that installed.  Important thing is you set the search path of your database, and then reconnect.  If you do all in same session, it won't work since the search_path db setting doesn't take effect until next connect.

Comment: Leaving that and installing the "postgis_tiger-geocoder" alone shows the same "ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist"

Comment: Also to verify what your search path is, run -- SHOW search_path;

Comment: Thats great.! I have been trying from the same session and upon reconnecting I could able to create the extension with no problem. Thanks for the tip. I would need to load the data for the tiger table so as to use reverse geocode. I will check that and keep posting, if there are any issues.

Comment: Which version of postgis_tiger_geocoder are you using? I just recently pushed out changes to support TIGER 2015 (but this is only available in upcoming PostGIS 2.2.0).  If you want to help test -- you could pull extension files from windows build (they will work on linux as well). http://postgis.net/windows_downloads (just pick same version of PostGIS you are running, and copy the share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder* files